# Cannot find part of path while uploading image to a folder in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, ravendb

I am uploading a profile picture of a user to a folder and saving its path to RavenDB. But my code is giving me an error that part of path is not found. On this line

```
file.SaveAs(path);
```

Code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadPic(FileManagement fmanage, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {


        string email = User.Identity.Name;

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var FileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", Guid.NewGuid(), file.ContentType);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Dta/Uploads"), FileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);

            using (var session = DocumentStore.OpenSession("RavenMemberShip"))
            {

                var query = from q in Session.Query<Registration>() where q.Email == email select q;
                if (query.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var updated in query)
                    {
                        fmanage.FileName = FileName;
                        fmanage.Path = path;
                        session.SaveChanges();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else ModelState.AddModelError("", "Remove the errors and try again");
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: it must be `App_Data` in your `Server.MapPath("~/App_Dta/Uploads")`

Comment: i have changed it to App_Data but the same error message i am getting.

Comment: Exceptions details are Exception Details: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\users\wasfa\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MvcMembership\MvcMembership\App_Data\Uploads\daed3def-df2b-4406-aa9e-c1995190aa6d.image\jpeg'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typing error in your path...

Replace...

```
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Dta/Uploads"), FileName);
```

With...

```
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads"), FileName);
```

You also need to make sure you have the relevant permissions to write to this directory.

Based on your error, the filepath looks incorrect.

> c:\users\wasfa\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\MvcMembership\MvcMembership\App_Data\Uploads\daed3def-df2b-4406-aa‌​9e-c1995190aa6d.image\jpeg

is **daed3def-df2b-4406-aa‌​9e-c1995190aa6d.image\jpeg** the name of the file?

Try:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadPic(FileManagement fmanage, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    string email = User.Identity.Name;

    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var FileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", Guid.NewGuid(), Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));            
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Dta/Uploads"), FileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);

        using (var session = DocumentStore.OpenSession("RavenMemberShip"))
        {

            var query = from q in Session.Query<Registration>() where q.Email == email select q;
            if (query.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var updated in query)
                {
                    fmanage.FileName = FileName;
                    fmanage.Path = path;
                    session.SaveChanges();

                }
            }
        }
    }
    else ModelState.AddModelError("", "Remove the errors and try again");
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I have removed this typing error but the same exception i am getting Exception Details: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path
 'c:\users\wasfa\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MvcMembership\MvcMembership\App_Data\Uploads\daed3def-df2b-4406-aa9e-c1995190aa6d.image\jpeg'.

Comment: @Wasfa, you failed to mention the full error in the question which would have been helpful.  The file path looks wrong.

Comment: @Wasfa, i have updated the portion of code that creates your filename.  This should now work.

Comment: Thank you!..It is worling now...:-)

Comment: @Wasfa, you're best off posting a question since the answer would be lost in a comment

Comment: Imahe path is in double forward slash form.How can i store it as single slash.??

Answer (score 0):

Before `file.SaveAs(path)`, try to check directory exist, if not, create one,

```
if(CreateFolderIfNeeded(path);
{
    file.SaveAs(path);
}
```

A private function to create directory if needed,

```
private static bool CreateFolderIfNeeded(string path)
        {
            bool result = true;
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                try
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                { result = false; }
            }
            return result;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `var FileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", Guid.NewGuid(), file.ContentType);` line in your code.

The file.ContentType will not return the extension of the file you are uploading. It shuold be like **daed3def-df2b-4406-aa‌​9e-c1995190aa6d.jpeg** instead of **daed3def-df2b-4406-aa‌​9e-c1995190aa6d.image\jpeg**

find the extension from the uploaded file using substring.

Hope this help